# How to save complicated nested dictionary to clipboard and then to excel

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, nested, clipboard

I have a loop function that returns a complicated nested dictionary each time, which can be simplified like this:

```
d= {
  "key1":"A", "key2":"B", "cumulative score":0.1, "direct score":0.4, "depth":0, 
  "chain":[
{"key1":"A1", "key2":"B1", "cumulative score":0.2, "direct score":0.5, "depth":1, 
  "chain":[{"key1":"A11", "key2":"B11","cumulative score":0.3, "direct score":0.6, "depth":2, "chain":[]}, 
         {"key1":"A12", "key2":"B12","cumulative score":0.5, "direct score":0.7, "depth":2, "chain":[]}]
},
{"key1":"A2", "key2":"B2","cumulative score":0.1, "direct score":0.2,"depth":1,
  "chain":[None, 
         {"key1":"A22", "key2":"B22","cumulative score":0.1, "direct score":0.5, "depth":2, "chain":[]}]
}
    ]
```

}

My real dictionary can go up to "depth"=10+, and can have a lot more data. Since I need to manually check the returned value in excel, I find copying the output window to clipboard and then to excel can create a clear way of showing the data like this:

[image]

So I want to add such a function to do this at the end of my loop function. I have tried this

```
def add_to_clipboard(text):
import tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w") as fp:
    fp.write(text)
    fp.flush()
    command = "pbcopy < {}".format(fp.name)
    os.system(command)
```

**My question is: I got the following error, and I don't know to save the data on clipboard to excel.** Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-8afb2d14c221> in <module>()
----> 1 add_to_clipboard(result_test)

<ipython-input-101-89cb10853a94> in add_to_clipboard(text)
  2     import tempfile
  3     with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w") as fp:
----> 4         fp.write(text)
  5         fp.flush()
  6         command = "pbcopy < {}".format(fp.name)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\envs\Battery\lib\tempfile.py in func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
481             @_functools.wraps(func)
482             def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
--> 483                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
484             # Avoid closing the file as long as the wrapper is alive,
485             # see issue #18879.

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not dict
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says you can write into file only string objects,here text variable is dictionary. Main this is  write() accepts only string object. So you can convert your dictionary object into string

```
import json
jsonStr = json.dumps(text)
print(type(jsonStr ))
fp.write(text)
```

Comment: But then I got the error "Object of type 'Activity' is not JSON serializable"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to export into an excel-like format would be to convert your `json` into a `pandas` dataframe and export it as a `csv`. Then you can open the file in a spreadsheet

```
import pandas as pd

out_file = 'my_file.csv'
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
df.to_csv(out_file)
```

Comment: I know pandas can write to csv easily, but my nested dictionary is too complex to be written into a table unfortunately.

Comment: If it can be exported as an Excel spreadsheet, then should be able to be a DataFrame as well, right? Have you tried the above code to see if it works? If not can you post an error?

Comment: I tried and found it can export the data to excel spreadsheet, but the format is not what I wanted (as shown in the picture in the original post, which was achieved by pasting from clipboard). Since I need to do some manual checking, a huge chunk of nested dictionary in one cell makes it impossible to read and understand.